# When to ask invited users to register?

Tags: registration, onboarding, b2b, personalisation

I work with a SaaS B2B company and I'm currently working on enhancing the onboarding experience for invited users to use the app. Note that we want to learn about the user from the beginning so we can personalize the onboarding and focus on specific features related to the user's role.

When should I ask users to insert their password for registration? After clicking on the invitation link from email, or after I capture their information?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the user to register when it becomes impossible to deliver them additional value without a user account. This will depend on your application, but an example of when an account is absolutely necessary is when you need to save the user's progress for later.

Note that account creation can be delayed for quite some time if you are working on a mobile app, since, most of the data can be retained locally.